# 404 in my webapp

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

i want to learn Spring MVC and I downloaded a little mvc project from a tutorial site. I imported it to eclipse but i always get an 404. I don't think there is a mistake in the code.
I have no clue and googled for hours. Would be glad if you can help me.
I'm using tomcat 7.
Here is the link for the project:
http://www.roseindia.net/spring/HelloWorld.zip
Thanks in advance. -Paul

Answer (score 5):

Use the [petclinic app](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html). roseindia.net is *not reliable*. And whetever the problem is, look for stacktraces in log files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bozho. I will do the petclinic app. But i want to know what the problem is. I have several log files in the logs directory but i can't find an error. Where do i have to look up ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I compleatly agree with Bozho.

One important additional hint: The example you used based on the old Spring 2.0 style for web controllers. This style is somehow deprecated. The new annotation based (`@Controller`, `@RequestMapping`) is much nicer (and need much less xml).

(Btw: the jars are old too Spring 2.5.x)

Comment: Thank you very much Ralph. I'll stick to the official Springsource and in Version 3.